# How to map images in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-class-based-component

So in a Reactjs class component, I have an array in my state like this:

```
myArray: [
   { number: 1, title: 'Users', image: '../../../assets/images/website/homepage/users.png' },
   { number: 2, title: 'Clients', image: '../../../assets/images/website/homepage/clients.png' },
   { number: 3, title: 'Admin', image: '../../../assets/images/website/homepage/admins.png' },
]
```

and I mapped the array this way:

```
{this.state.myArray.map((item, index) => (
   <Box key={index} className="col-sm-12">
      <img src={ item.image } className="img-fluid" alt={item.title} />
      <Typography variant="h4">{item.number}</Typography>
   </Box>
))}
```

Now, everything works fine, except the image that doesn't display, I really don't understand where I'm getting it wrong.

Note that, if I copy one of the image links directly inside the src using require method, it works. Kindly help.

Comment: When your website gets built, the path to the images is probably different. Usually the JS is compiled into a single bundle at the root of the build folder, so the path from that bundle to the image is different than the path from the JS source file to the image. Check that paths and file locations of your *compiled* JS

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: @OlawaleOladiran depends how you're building your app. But there should be a folder where the built stuff gets put when it's compiled.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can [require dynamically with proper expression](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-with-expression):

Change `image` to (**remove** `../../../assets/images/website/homepage/` and  `.png`):

```
const myArray = [
  {
    number: 1,
    title: 'Users',
    image: 'users',
  },
  {
    number: 2,
    title: 'Clients',
    image: 'clients',
  },
  {
    number: 3,
    title: 'Admin',
    image: 'admins',
  },
]
```

And to render at UI (**add** directory **path** and the **extension** inside `require`):

```
{myArray.map((item, index) => (
  <Box key={index} className="col-sm-12">
    <img
      src={require('../../../assets/images/website/homepage/' +
        item.image +
        '.png')}
      className="img-fluid"
      alt={item.title}
    />
    <Typography variant="h4">{item.number}</Typography>
  </Box>
))}
```

**Why it works?:**

Webpack can understand this expression, by [generating context about directory and extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62095265/2873538), and can load all the matching modules.

Comment: I tried this way but my application becomes blank...

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing require.

Like:

```
<img src={require(item.image)} />
```

Comment: I did that, but I'm getting: `Cannot find module '../../../assets/images/website/homepage/users.png'` error

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Use require in the array */

myArray: [
   { number: 1, title: 'Users', image: require('../../../assets/images/website/homepage/users.png’) },
   { number: 2, title: 'Clients', image: require('../../../assets/images/website/homepage/clients.png') },
   { number: 3, title: 'Admin', image: require('../../../assets/images/website/homepage/admins.png') },
]
```