# react match required image cache busted images to json object property

Tags: reactjs, typescript

``
I'm loading a JSON object from an API and deserializing it into an array of objects

the array has a property for the image name, in react I need to match the JSON object property name to that of the relevant required image

example :

```
const foo = require("./images/foo.png");
const bar = require("./images/bar.png");
const loo = require("./images/loo.png");
const mee = require("./images/mee.png");

const foo: myObjectArray[] = useFetchCustomAPIHook()

/* data example:
const foo = {
  "images":
    [
      { "id": 1, "name": "foo.png" },
      { "id": 2, "name": "bar.png" },
      { "id": 3, "name": "loo.png" },
      { "id": 4, "name": "mee.png" }
    ]
};
*/

foo.every((item:any) => {
  /* TO DO: Match name to relevant required item */
  // Pseudo :
  // match item.name  to relevant const e.g. foo || bar  || loo || mee etc
})
```

because require adds cache busting the names are './images/foo.fbcb91799ceba75b2e3a.png'

I could use a regex but it would have to match test all const required items against the given item for every iteration

```
foo.every((item:any) => {
    const t1  = foo.match(/[^\\/]+?(?=\.{1}\w){1}\b/i)[0]
    const t2 =  bar.match(/[^\\/]+?(?=\.{1}\w){1}\b/i)[0]
    const t3  = loo.match(/[^\\/]+?(?=\.{1}\w){1}\b/i)[0]
if(t1 === item.name){
    item.name = t1
}else if( t2 === item.name){
    item.name = t2
}else ....
```

Also, there are other places in the code that update the array and set its property name to different images...so I tried using

```
const foo = "foo.png";
const bar = "bar.png";
const loo = "loo.png";
const mee = "mee.png";`
```

and then in the HTML render, I called the required method to load the image like so:

```
function loadImage(content: any): string {
    if (content) {
      return require(`./images/${content}`)
    }
    return ''
  }
...
 return (
    <>
      <div>
          {foo.map((item: any, index: number) => {
            return (
              <div key={index}>
                <img
                  data-cell-id={item.index}
                  data-cell-index={index}
                  alt={loadImage(item?.name)}
                  src={loadImage(item?.name)}
                />
              </div>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

This works for the first required const item but as soon as a different item is passed to the function where the name is for a different image it throws an error:

> Cannot find module './/assets/images/bar.png'

But if I change the consts so that `const foo = 'bar.png'` and `bar const = 'foo.png'` then it throws

> Cannot find module './/assets/images/foo.png'

So it's not that it can't find the image but rather that as soon as the image is different it fails but I'm not entirely sure why?

Hope I explained this properly, all the above code is mostly Pseudo'ish so it might not run, it's just to give the general idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

worked it out using this solution, not sure why i didn't find it before

[How to map images in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62110521/how-to-map-images-in-reactjs)